# How to perform actions in TFS 2015 using REST api

Tags: rest, tfs-2015

I have TFS2015.2 installed on a server (my company server). I'm trying to do some HTTP requests from Fiddler to retrieve some information (builds available, ...) but I always have an http 401 Unauthorized error.
I'm using a basic authentication through the http Authorization header.
Is there any documentation on TFS2015 and REST apis?
What could be wrong?

Comment: Is Basic Auth enabled on your TFS server? The default is NTLM only.

Comment: Why would anyone need to change the default for local network authentication?

Answer (score 0):

As @jessehouwing mentioned, you need to enable Basic Auth.

1. check your IIS to see whether the Basic authentication service role is installed.
2. go to IIS Manager, select Team Foundation Server -- Authentication and disable everything other than **Basic Authentication**. Then do the same for the tfs node under Team Foundation Server.
3. restart your IIS.

This way basic authentication will be enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the server configuration. So, I have to use NTLM authentication... but does anyone know how to construct a NTLM authorization header?

Comment: I don't think NTLM authorization will work. Check link https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/rest/basics. You can use basic authentication with your app while you're just getting the integration to work. To avoid your users having to sign in to yet another service, implement OAuth integration.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - OP says its an On Premise installation.